# jqGrid - add Checkbox in toolbar dropdown

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm trying to add checkbox in dropdown of jqGrid Toolbar, but I can't able to figure out how to do it. I have a multiselect box which is working fine but I want to replace it with checkbox which will be visible on dropdown.

My code is

```
{
    name: 'Status',
    index: 'account.status',
    searchoptions: {
        sopt: ['eq'],
        value: ":All;0:Pending;1:Warming;2:Running;3:Dead;4:ID Verification",
        multiple: true
    },
    stype: 'select'
}
```

> jqGrid js version 5.1.1

I have also attached screenshot for better understanding.

**This is what I have**

[image]

**This is what I need**

[image]

Any suggestion will be very helpfull for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Complete example: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultiselectIn.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can achieve dropdown with checkbox by using [ui.multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget).

*Include this 2 files*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/ui.multiselect.css" />
<script src="path/to/your/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*Then try this code.*

```
{
name: 'Status',
 index: 'account.status',
 stype: 'select',
 searchoptions: {
  sopt: ['eq'],
  value: ":All;0:Pending;1:Warming;2:Running;3:Dead;4:ID Verification",
  multiple: true,
  dataInit: function(e){
  $(e).multiselect({
  minWidth: 120,
   selectedList: 2,
   noneSelectedText: "Any"
  });
  }
 }
}
```